# How Can i Parse the sms text to textboxes

Tags: c#

how can can i do this ? i can't get the return value and i can understand how regex work .

```
 string value = "+CMT:"+639231568462"," ","18/10/07,14:31:32+32" HELLO"
    ";
    Regex r = new Regex("");
    Match m = r.Match(value);

    while(m.Success)
    {
          string number = m.Group[0].toString();
          string Date = m.Group[1].toString();
          string Time = m.Group[2].toString();
          string Mesage= m.Group[3].toString();

    }
```

OUTPUT

```
number = +639231568462;
date = 18/10/07;
time = 14:31:32;
message = HELLO;
```

Comment: this question is about c# and regular expression, but it is not database related. So it is off topic here. Maybe it is suitavle for https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

First your string is not valid. This will display compile time errors in your IDE

for simply parsing text you can use the split() method.

```
 string[] a = value.Split(',');
```

see this fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/0amHEP

Comment: what is happening is i'm receiving a message comming from sms / gsm using  an "uart" , and i can't parse it.